# «Следует что» или «следует, что»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, сложное-предложение

Из текста на английском языке следует(,) что возраст ученика не важен, а из перевода на русский язык — что и это имеет значение.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопрос можно оставить. Вполне возможно, что автор просто не смог его правильно сформулировать. Почему в одном случае перед "что" нет запятой, а в другом она нужна.

Answer (score 1):

*Из текста на английском языке следует, **что** возраст ученика не важен, **а** из перевода на русский язык — что и это имеет значение.*

Часть до союза "а" представляет собой сложноподчинённое предложение. В нём главное предложение (*Из текста на английском языке следует*) соединяется с придаточным (*возраст ученика не важен*) с помощью союза **что.**
Перед союзом по правилам требуется запятая — придаточные предложения отделяются от главного запятыми.

Во второй большой части (после союза "а") пропущено сказуемое "следует" (оно восстанавливается по смыслу: *из перевода на русский язык **следует,** что...*), поэтому поставлено тире. Оно поглотило запятую, необходимую перед другим союзом "что".

[Сложноподчинённые предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/735-21_obschaya_harakteristika_slozhnopodchinennyh_predlozhenii.html)
[Тире в неполном предложении (§16)](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/)